# Java binary translation?

Tags: java

I am trying to find some code that will easily break now a binary string.  I'm not even sure I'm asking this question correctly, but I want to get the value of each "active bit". For example, if I have a binary string of 100000001, I would like to return the values 256, 1 in an array. I'm trying to figure this out so I can use a lookup table in SQL which has an integer column and a text column.  The integer column will be used to determine which text values will be written to a new table. So, the value "Text1" at 1, and "Text 2" at 256 would both be written to the new table, but the number submitted to get those values would be 257.
I know I'm rambling, but I would input a value, 257, and I convert it to a binary string of 100000001. Now I want some code to break that binary string into two values... 1 and 256.  Am I making any sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a code writing service. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Ask about:
Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development tools

Don't ask about:
Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
Product or service recommendations or comparisons
Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Comment: Never mind, I'll just work on converting some old C code.  I figured Java would have a tool for it.  It's so easy to convert an integer to binary, I figured there would be an easy way to read the bits from the binary form.  Thanks for reminding me that this isn't a "code writing service". This is literally the smallest part of the program I've been working on and maintaining for the last 2 years.

Comment: I'm not sure if converting to a binary string was part of your question, but you can use [`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-).

Comment: Yes, I did that.  I took the integer 257 and converted it to the Binary String and got 100000001.  The issue is, I need to pull the table values at 256 and 1 to add to another SQL table, so I some how need programmatically get the value 256 from and 1 so that I can pull the data from those rows of the table.  We just thought there might be a better way then looping through the string to get the value of each bit.

Comment: @user3508197 If you showed the code you're currently using to loop through the string and get your desired output, there would really be nothing wrong with your question. It's just that we expect askers to show everything they have tried and researched before asking, so that they can ask a high-quality question.

Comment: I can create a loop, no problem.  I was simply looking to see if Java had a built in function of some kind to break this out, rather than having to run through a loop. Judging from the responses, I'm guess java does not have such a function, and I'll just have to go with building a class or method that will break it out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert to a binary string if you use [`Integer.highestOneBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit-int-). You can loop through the one bits, filling in an array of size [`Integer.bitCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-) with each call to `Integer.highestOneBit`. Afterwards, you can xor with the value of the highest bit to remove it from the number.

```
public static int[] getOneBits(int num) {
    int[] oneBits = new int[Integer.bitCount(num)];
    for (int i = 0; i < oneBits.length; i++) {
        oneBits[i] = Integer.highestOneBit(num);
        num ^= oneBits[i];
    }
    return oneBits;
}
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/0vQ3kL)

This will produce an array, where all of the values are powers of 2 in descending order, where the sum of all the elements will be the original number. For example, `257` will produce `[256, 1]`, and `127` will produce `[64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do.  I'm bad at vocalizing my question.